# Quiescensce search for Nine Men's Morris

Tags: artificial-intelligence

First of all, is it worth it to implement a quiesce search for such a game? And secondly, if a quiesce search is indeed worth, what should this search consider (eg. closing mills, blocking mills, etc)?

Thanks,
Ivan